# Import exported SVN

Tags: svn, import, export

I have a bit specific question. How would I import an exported SVN repo?
I have already read few of the import/export questions around here, but my case is more specific. What I got was an exported SVN repo (with my projects' source), now I need to import it again. How would I do it?

Comment: Do you still have access to the old repository?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If it has been exported,all SVN specific files will have been removed. You create a new repository in the same way you would for any other source code.

Comment: Well that last comment (by Neil) settles that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Dave is right about there being confusion around the meaning of the word `export`, but there seems to be some confusion as to the commands involved in his answer.

If you have a directory structure in which you see the files that look like the source files in your project, and there are no `.svn` subdirectories, you have the result of an `svn export ...` command, and you *don't have any repository history*, you only have a snapshot of the project.  In this case, you create a new subversion repo on your new server using the `svnadmin create ...` command, and then use `svn import ....` to commit that snapshot into your new repository.

If you got a single file with a bunch of stuff in it that looks like it has parts of the source code mixed in with lots of other stuff, then you got what is called a "dump file".  This dump file contains your project, *including all history* for that project.  In this case, you create your new repository with `svnadmin create ...`, then load the data into a repository using the `svnadmin load ...` command.

After that, you will want to use `svn co ...` to checkout a working copy that you can then develop in.

If what you got was a snapshot of the project, I would encourage you to go back to them and try to get a dump file instead... source control history is valuable.

Comment: I'm very new to svn migration and right now struggling with it. Is this last 'svn co' part necessary on the server? I think you mean that after the server operation is complete the user has to checkout the local working copy, isn't it?

Comment: Enmos: 'svn co' is for checking out a working copy where you will be doing your development, not for the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have access to the old repository, then the fact that the files are exported from another repository is irrelevant.  Just `import` them as you would any other files that you want to put into Subversion.  You will not have any of the old repository’s history.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is confusion between "export" here.

In svn world, "export" means to make a copy of a directory structure and remove all suversion metadata (.svn directories and files). If you received this kind of export, then you have a directory structure that is completely independent of subversion (it's no longer under svn control). So you'll need to add this dir structure to svn just as if you were to create a brand new directory with files and need to commit those to subversion

Outside of svn world, "export" sometimes means to create a full backup. In svn, creating a full backup of an entire repository is achieved using `svnadmin dump` command. If this is the type of export you received, then you probably have a single ["dump file"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump). In order to restore a dump file, use the `svnadmin load` to restore it back into a subversion repository. More specifically, you'll need to upload your copy of the export onto a computer that hosts the subversion repository and then do a `svnadmin load`. Then, you'll be able to check out the dirs and files as normal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, @retractile, I got the commands mixed up and corrected them.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the old repository, you can use `svnadmin dump` to export and `svnadmin load` to import it, as described in more detail [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450/how-do-i-export-and-then-import-a-subversion-repo).

Comment: I do not, I just got the export.