# How can I change the SVN URL in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ankhsvn

In my office, I have a working repository, where I am able to work on my laptop to modify files and commit them to that repository. I am using a local URL for this, which points directly to the PC containing the repository. Additionally, we published this repository for external users as well, so they are able to make changes to the repository without being on our local network. All is working fine there. However, my laptop which normally using the local connection, now needs to be moved to one of those external locations. I would like to be able to change the URL in my solution in Visual Studio, without having to 'create project from SVN'

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to switch subversion repository in Visual Studio using AnkhSVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276952/how-to-switch-subversion-repository-in-visual-studio-using-ankhsvn)

Answer (score 7):

Navigate to View -> Pending Changes.

You can see the Pending Changes prompt at the bottom.Then Select the drop down on the top right and select other option. Provide the new URL and click on OK button.

Done!

Answer (score 4):

Whay you need is `relocate` (NOT switch) to tell your working copy that the URL of the repository changed (from your local URL to the external URL).

In the thread Collin linked to is most likely the correct answer:
[How to switch subversion repository in Visual Studio using AnkhSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276952/how-to-switch-subversion-repository-in-visual-studio-using-ankhsvn/2285050#2285050)

Answer (score 0):

[How to switch subversion repository in Visual Studio using AnkhSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276952/how-to-switch-subversion-repository-in-visual-studio-using-ankhsvn)

Comment: Better to put this in comments, as it doesn't directly answer the question