# How to change repository url of a project

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I'm new to AnkhSVN. Before the problem occurs, I've done some experiments
and now I can't get AnkhSVN work.

I have a project named SGS. I let AnkhSVN manage it, and its repository uri was
`file:///E:/reporsitory`.

Later I deleted the folder `E:/reporsitory`. Now I start Visual Studio 2010,
try to reset repository uri of SGS project. It seems that Subversion
->Switch Project.. would work but it pops up a dialog saying can't switch
since it is not in repository yet.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413269/subversion-server-name-change-with-ankhsvn and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049690/how-can-i-change-the-svn-url-in-visual-studio

Comment: @pmod Thanks. They may be helpful, but I have uninstalled ankhsvn... Well, I may check them when I'm at leisure.