# subversion server name change with ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

IT has moved the location of the svn server to a different box.  As a result all the source control paths need changed.  I can't find where to do it in VS2010+AnkSvn.  The change source control dialog (File-Subversion-Change Source Control) lists the SCC binding URL, but as a read-only value and doesn't appear to provide any way to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the "Switch solution" button on the Pending Changes toolbar. Press it, enter the new URL and press OK.

Comment: Also you can right click on solution or project and on the Subversion menu the option "switch project" is available.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on project in VS, goto subversion and select 'switch project'. here you can change your svn server.