# How to change SVN source control repository - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

This is a very simple question - How can I remove Source Control from my solution and projects in order to change the SVN repository ?

I have an old project linked to an old repository, trying to move to a new one, and unable to figure out how.

The Actual place in Visual Studio that suppose to enable this is Grayed out. 
Removing the .svn files form the folder doesn't apply as they are not there....

using the latest version of ankhSVN.

Comment: Tortoisesvn is a pretty good explorer add-in which allows you to perform these tasks with a right-click of the checked-out repository. I don't know how to accomplish this from within visual studio, so this is only proposed as an alternative approach. The svn term for this is `switching` the repository. If it's simply a manner of changing server/protocol, then you're doing a relocate of the repository

Comment: I don't have it installed, there must be a way to do it from within visual studio....

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual2013. Go--> Tool----> Optioins--->sourcesControl
And Cuurent Sources Plug in None.
just set This. if not retuen feedback...

Comment: didn't help. the solution and project still subversion aware.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to change the SVN respository that you're pointing to. There is [another Question And Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276952/how-to-switch-subversion-repository-in-visual-studio-using-ankhsvn), but it seems pretty ugly.

Having installed the latest version of ankhSVN on Visual Studio 2013, it seems pretty trivial to relocate to a different SVN respository.

Right click on the Solution -> Subversion -> Switch Solution

On the menu, you should have an entry pointing to the current location of the solution. If the repository is the same, but under a different URL e.g. changing hostname, directory, etc, then simply change the relevant pieces in the URL and hit enter.

It will prompt you that the root you've specified is different from the one that you're currently using and you can simply relocate it from one to the other - i.e. choose to relocate. It will then prompt you a second time to switch, but this should be a free change.

If the new repository is different to the old one i.e. it's somewhere completely different in a different repository with a different repository ID then you're going to have to do some form of manual changing by following the instructions on the other answer.

> If you want to remove the svn metadata for the project, it's in a *single* directory called .svn at the root of the solution that was checked out from subversion, as well as removing the information in the `.sln` file that mentions `AnkhSVN` (it's probably the only entries mentioned in a specific GlobalSection in the file mentioning source control). That purges all the svn data from the solution.

Comment: Thanks, was exactly what I was looking for when I found this post!! Since I moved my solution to a new folder, I had to get source ctrl to point to solution in its new flder. For @Dani question, if I read it right, wants to remove SVN from the solution all together. Not sure how via srce ctrl, but it can be done with SVN software, like TortoiseSVN. **Instruts:** `1.) Navigate to the solutions flder in SVN repository. 2.) Right click the folder and find 'TortoiseSVN'. 3.) Now find 'Export'. 4.) Choose fldr path to export too, and click 'OK'.` Now there is the full fldr w/out the svn sub fldrs.