# How to import/export repository from SVN to new SVN

Tags: linux, svn, redhat, repository

I have an old Subversion on one server and another new one on another server.

I would like to export the head revision from the old repository and import it into the new one.

I have tried the below which seems to export, but I can't get it to import into the new one.

```
svn export --depth immediates file:///repositories/repo1/ /home/me/repo-export
```

This is what I am trying for import:

```
svn import /home/me/repo-export/ /svnroot/
```

How can this be done via the Linux ([Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 4) command line?

Comment: you mention you want to 'export the head'... are you uninterested in preserving the history of the repository?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450/how-do-i-export-and-then-import-a-subversion-repo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to migrate only the most recent version without the history. However, I strongly recommend to migrate everything. The migration is explained in detail in the online book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html):

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate

In short:

- Use `svnadmin dump /path/to/old/repo` or `svnrdump dump old-url` to create a dump of the old repository.
- Use `svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo` or `svnrdump load new-url` to load the dump into the new repository.