# Subversion: How to export *all* projects in a repository?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a subversion repository with 40-50 individual projects stored in it.  How can I export all these projects/trees/(or whatever you call them) so I can migrate them to another machine?  Bonus points if I don't have to do each one individually :)

Comment: What do you mean by "migrate to another machine"? Are you moving the repository to a new server? Trying to get a working copy on another machine? Just wanting to get a copy of the files in your repository?

Comment: Yes, moving to a new server.

Comment: Then you probably want to `svn dump` and then `svn load`, or just copy the repository folder, as suggested in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450/how-do-i-export-and-then-import-a-subversion-repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` as then you don't have to worry about file system level compatibility.

Note that SVN stores everything on the repository level and not the project level. A repository is like blobs of data. If you wanted to separate the projects into different repositories, you'd have a big job on your hands. To merely migrate the whole repository together is easy! Just make sure nobody is writing to the repository while you are taking the dump.