# svn java api "Unable to open an ra_local session to URL"

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, svnkit

I need to automatically checkout all svn revisions to do some repo mining.

I wrote a java code using svnkit (org.tmatesoft.svn_1.8.5.standalone_2)
The code works nicely when i access the url of the repository 
but when i do checkout using file:/// protocol, the following svn exception appears.

I searched and found lots of recommendations like version mismatch in client and server. but i do not have client server. I only have a java code.

i checked out a revison recursively in my local drive and then i expect to use the repo in local drive to automatically checkout older revisions in offline mode

I can't figure out the solution and i am a novice.

Do you have any solution?

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///c:/repos/lego'
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///c:/repos/lego'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.openRepository(FSRepository.java:796)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.fs.FSRepository.testConnection(FSRepository.java:105)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepository.getRepositoryRoot(SVNRepository.java:323)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgAbstractUpdate.checkout(SvnNgAbstractUpdate.java:768)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:16)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgCheckout.run(SvnNgCheckout.java:10)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgOperationRunner.run(SvnNgOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1149)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:777)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout(SVNUpdateClient.java:662)
    at SVNHelper.doCheckou(SVNHelper.java:77)
    at process2.main(process2.java:20)
```

Comment: "i checked out a revison recursively in my local drive" -- Does that mean that the directory `C:\repos\lego` is not a SVN repository, but a checked out SVN directory? In that case, you cannot check it out from there.

Comment: Yes.I tested two options: a folder which i did automatic checkout and a folder that i did checkout using tortoise.

Comment: So, how can i have svn repo locally in my local machine?

Comment: You did not exactly explain what you are trying to do ... but ... you can only checkout from a SVN repository. The file: protocol is just another prefix for a URL. Nothing strange. So, if you have setup a SVN repo on your local machine, it is possible to checkout from there with a file URL. But I think, that you want to access a remote SVN repo. So you simply must checkout from there.

Comment: I am doing repo mining and i need to checkout nearly 2000 revision from a remote repository. I think it is faster to transfer the repository to my local drive and then run my mining code. I do not know how to do it?

Comment: Checking out also means that you only have a specific revision of your repo on your local machine. You cannot use the working directory (the checked out one) and "see" it as the SVN repo. Point. Checking out _must_ be done from the SVN repo.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. How can I have the remote svn repo in local directory

Comment: Thank you again. I created a svn repo and syn it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Seelenvirtuose

I used checked out folder as a repository and, therefore it was unable to open ra_local session..

I solved the problem by creating local repository and syncing it with remote one. To do so i followed the recommended steps in [1, 2]

Now it works :)

[1] [How do I export (and then import) a Subversion repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450/how-do-i-export-and-then-import-a-subversion-repo) 
[2] http://slopjong.de/2010/01/20/let-svn-accept-revision-propchanges/